# Laravel not uploading svg image even though it is in allowed types

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload

I am trying to upload svg from laravel and it is giving this error.

```
The icon must be a file of type: png, svg, gif, jpeg.
```

This is the code of validator.

```
$rules = array(
    'image' => 'mimes:png,gif,svg,jpeg|max:10000' // max 10000kb
);
```

Comment: did u try juest: mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg?

Comment: Yes tried same error coming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

`$rules = array(
 'image' => 'image'
  );`

It supports jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg file type.

Check this for more info. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-image